# VBA Code to Search closed workbook for a match based off an Input Box and pull entire row to Active Workbook

Tags: excel, macros, vba

Searched around and found a few threads regarding VBA import the first sheet of a closed workbook, I'm trying to search through sheet of closed workbook for a set word that has been type using inputbox. Once the value is found to pull through the entire row and paste into second workbook which is active.

Below is the Code ive been working on any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Dim srcWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim destWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim srcWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim destWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim destPath As String
    Dim destname As String
    Dim destsheet As String
    Set srcWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set srcWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim vnt_Input As String

    vnt_Input = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Client Name", "Client Name")

    destPath = "C:\test\"
    destname = "Test2.xlsm"
    destsheet = "Sheet1"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set destWorkbook = Workbooks(destname)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(destPath & destname)
    CloseIt = True
    End If

    For Each c In Range("A2:W100").Cells

    If InStr(c, "vnt_Input") > 0 Then

    c.EntireRow.Copy
    destWorkbook.Activate
    destWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset     (1)     .EntireRow.Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone,SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
srcWorkbook.Activate
```

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple changes you need to make. See whole code below. I will comment the changes:

```
Dim srcWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim destWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim srcWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim destWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim destPath As String
    Dim destname As String
    Dim destsheet As String
    Set srcWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set srcWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim vnt_Input As String

    vnt_Input = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Client Name", "Client Name")

    destPath = "C:\test\"
    destname = "Quick Test.xlsm"
    destsheet = "Sheet1"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set destWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(destPath & destname)
    CloseIt = True
    End If

    For Each c In wbTarget.Sheets("Companies").Range("A2:W100") 'No need for the .Cells here

       If InStr(c, vnt_Input) > 0 Then 'vnt_Input is a variable that holds a string, so you can't put quotes around it, or it will search the string for "vnt_Input"

          c.EntireRow.Copy
          destWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone,SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False 'Please don't use Select and Activate. There is almost never a need for it.
       End if
    Next c
```

Comment: Kyle thanks for your quick reply!, I have made the changes you have highlighted , macro runs but doesn't produce any results on the workbook. The results need to begin to copy from 5th Row on the "Master" sheet (Sheet 1)

Comment: You should take out `On Error Resume Next` and try again. That line will mask any errors and make debugging much harder. The code above should work.

Comment: I have removed On Error Resume Next still cycles through but produces no results, to clarify the workbook I wish to pull the results from is called Quick Test.xlsm and the one for the results to be copied to Test2.xlsm. Both reside in the same folder.

Comment: I don't see "Quick Test.xlsm" in your code, so I assume that workbook isn't being opened at all.

Comment: This is where the issue is would I replace the Test2.xlsm at the dest path,dest name and dest sheet to correspond with the Quick Test.xlsm workbook ? But I assume I then need to put in some code to paste the data into the Test2.xlsm workbook. Thanks again for the help , and sticking with me

Comment: I will respond in a couple hours.

Comment: Sorry, now I am confused again. Which workbook and sheet do you want to search, and which workbook and sheet are you trying to copy to?

Comment: Haha I apologise for confusing you , I am trying to copy data from Quick Test.xlsm sheet 2 named "Companies" to the active workbook which will be Test2.xlsm sheet 1 named "Master"

Comment: Hopefully my previous comment made sense ? The workbook that is active that will import the data through will be Test2.xlsm , the source workbook is Quick Test.xlsm. Not sure how to write the code to highlight which workbook to copy from and which to paste from , thanks again for your help its really appreciated.

Comment: Bump @Kyle Any Ideas?

Comment: Thanks very much for your continued help , implemented your changes however when trying to run macro "Run-time error '424': Object required" when debug is run highlights " For Each c In wbTarget.Sheets("Companies").Range("A2:W100") " line

Comment: Check to make sure your workbook is opening in the line `Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(destPath & destname)`.

Comment: Apologies been away on business , how would I check this ? via debug mode?

Comment: Put a break on the line `CloseIt = True`. When the code breaks, type `?wbTarget.Name` and it should print the name of the workbook in the immediate window.